# ExpressionEngine Query Modul - retrieving related entries only from a particular category

Tags: expressionengine

I'm running into the limits of my SQL knowledge. I'm pulling related entries into a Safecracker form, as pull-down inputs, and want to retrieve only related entries of a particular category from the database. For example, I've got an 'events' channel, in which you can relate the event to an entry in a 'locations' channel. I don't need to see all of the possible venues, just ones from a particular category that relate to a particular type of event. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help.

I forgot to mention that I already have the query pulling out ALL of my related entries, but so far no luck filtering by category.

```
<label>RELATED ENTRY TEST</label>
<select name="event_rel_location" id="event_rel_location">
<option value="">--</option>
{exp:query sql="SELECT entry_id AS rel_entry_id, title AS rel_title, (SELECT rel_child_id FROM exp_relationships WHERE rel_id = '{event_rel_location}' LIMIT 10) AS rel_child_id FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE channel_id = 51 AND status='Open' ORDER BY title ASC "}
<option value="{rel_entry_id}" {if rel_child_id == rel_entry_id} selected="selected"{/if}>{rel_title}</option>
{/exp:query}
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yup, that'll be a tough query ... might be a better use of your time/budget to buy [Playa](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa), convert your relationship field to Playa, then use the Playa module tags instead, which allow you to restrict related and reverse-related entries by category (`{exp:playa:parents}` and `{exp:playa:children}`).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check into that as an option. My stubborn side wants to figure this out with the query module, but it could be that it's not worth it.